# remoteDebuggerPort vs --remote-debugger-port phantom.js JSON config

Tags: phantomjs

when I try to use following JSON config for phantom.js, remoteDebuggerPort parameter just gets ignored:

```
{
    "localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled": true,
    "webSecurityEnabled": false,
    "remoteDebuggerPort": 9001,
    "remoteDebuggerAutorun": "yes"
}
```

(every other parameter is OK)

And when I call it like:

phantomjs.exe --remote-debugger-port=9001 ... It works. Why is that?